# Can't edit MuiTypography-root

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue editing the child of MuiTypography where I want to remove the line-height from muitypography-root it has to be a solution that will only apply to this section. Below I've attached the jsx and a picture from the browser.

```
logo:{
        color: '#26262d',
        fontWeight: '600',
        mr: '8px',
        fontSize: '1.5rem',
        "& .MuiTypography-root": {
            lineHeight: 'none',
        }
```

[image: picture of styling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `lineHeight: 'none'` when you might be looking for `lineHeight: 'unset'`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

You can see this in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unset-lineheight-example-h8ognh?file=/src/App.js